# Django-uWSGI-nginx using https

Tags: python, django, nginx, https, uwsgi

I'm running my DJango app using uwsgi over nginx. 
it's currently working with these configurations:

> [uwsgi]
>   socket = :8002
>
> master = true
>
> env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=web_server.web_server.settings
>
> pythonpath = /tmp/src/
>
> wsgi-file = /tmp/src/web_server/web_server/wsgi.py
>
> chdir = /tmp/src/
>
> processes = 4
>
> threads = 2

and my nginx.conf file

> upstream django {
>
> server 127.0.0.1:8002;
>
> }
>
> server {
>
> listen      8000;
>
> server_name 192.168.56.104;
>
> charset     utf-8;
>
> # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
>
> location / {
>
> ```
>    uwsgi_pass  django;
>    include     /tmp/src/web_server/web_server/uwsgi_params;
> ```
>
> }

it's working with http.

I want to change it to work with https, but I can't find the right to configuration to make that work anywhere.

What should I change in my configuration in order to work with https?

I already have generated the certificate .

Comment: Every server setup and certificate file is a little different with requirements.  I would take a look at this documentation https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-nginx.htm and post specific technical questions if you can't get it working.

Comment: @ShlomiK If you have a solution, then please post it as an answer. Or if you think that the solution is too specific to your own situation, then delete the question. Thank you.

Comment: ok. adding the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris's comment helped me find the solution. 
in [SSL Certificate Installation in Nginx](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-nginx.htm)
you can find this:

> ssl    on;
>
> ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/your_domain_name.pem; (or bundle.crt)
>
> ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/your_domain_name.key;

I just added it to my nginx .conf file and that added https to my web server. so the final .conf file looks like this:

> upstream django {
>
> server 127.0.0.1:8002;
>
> }
>
> server {
>
> listen 8000;
>
> ssl    on;
>
> ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/your_domain_name.pem; (or bundle.crt)
>
> ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/your_domain_name.key;
>
> server_name 192.168.56.104;
>
> charset utf-8;
>
> ```
> # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
> ```
>
> location / {
>
> ```
>   uwsgi_pass  django;
>
>   include     /tmp/src/web_server/web_server/uwsgi_params;
> ```
>
> }